# Make sound notification using codeigniter and javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm new programmer, specially on codeigniter. I have a job to make sound notification on my project, when received data and save it on database.

I have the following code on my controller:

```
foreach($data["arr_data_lastalert"] as $data_last_alert) 
{
   if($data_last_alert["alertTypeId"]==1){
      echo "<script>soundSOS();</script>";
   }else if($data_last_alert["alertTypeId"]==2){
      echo "<script>soundOverspeed();</script>";
   }else if($data_last_alert["alertTypeId"]==3){
      echo "<script>soundGeofence();</script>";
   }

}
```

and here on my javascript:

```
function soundSOS(){
   $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source     src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RavensKrag/WireFu/master/data/beep-08.wav"   type="audio/wav"></audio>').appendTo('lastAlert');
   $('#chatAudio').play();
```

}

I have tried it and no result from code above. What should I do to it? Is there other way to make it run? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: you can use HTML 5 Web Sound APIs? =)

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript and use this link for that and you get sound notification

```
enter code here
```

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
jQuery(".navigation a").click(function(e){

    var nextPage = $(this).attr('href');//save reference to the clicked url

   jQuery("<audio>").attr({//create the audio object

        "hidden":true,

        "autostart":true,

        "loop":false,

        "src":"http:/yourpath/html/horse.mp3"

    }).bind("ended",function(){//when audio finishes playing update the page to new url

       document.location.href = nextPage

    }).appendTo("#dummy");//add the audio to the DOM

   jQuery("audio")[0].play();

    e.preventDefault();//preve`enter code here`nt the page from following the link right away

});`enter code here`
```

});